# Web Forms, Get submitted name for save?

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath-rules, save

I know how to submit and save, but I want the option to effectively have both to be truly available upon creation of the new document.

Basically, I have multiple submission connections, and this works fine. However, I want the ability to Save the new form as if it were submitted (i.e. had a document in the library).

So in other words, I should be able to save a partial form if it's new, and continue where I left off if it's not, and finally use the Submit button when I'm done with the form (which would submit the form to a different location, out of the "staging" area).

Is this possible? It seems like most answers are using the Infopath Filler, and require code (which apparently doesn't work on our server).

Answer (score 0):

You could use submit in both cases.
In your form have a checkbox that you tick if the form is complete. Promote this column out to the library and have a workflow check if it is checked, if so then the workflow can copy the item to location B and then delete the original.
But this assumes that your submit connection has no other functionality that would be broken using this method?

Comment: Right, it would be a little confusing to the users since we already trained on using the two differing buttons, and having a "Really submit" button would complicate things. At the moment (as a workaround) I have the form automatically submit as an incomplete form, have them close it (so they return to the library list), and then open it again, which allows the Save button to work as expected. Very klunky.